# kubectl - cert manager - credentials not found

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-ingress

I want to have TLS termination enabled on ingress (on top of kubernetes) on google cloud platform.

My ingress cluster is working, my cert manager is failing with the error message

```
textPayload:  "2018/07/05 22:04:00 Error while processing certificate during sync: Error while creating ACME client for 'domain': Error while initializing challenge provider googlecloud: Unable to get Google Cloud client: google: error getting credentials using GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable: open /opt/google/kube-cert-manager.json: no such file or directory
"
```

This is what I did in order to get into the current state:

- created cluster, deployment, service, ingress
- executed:

  gcloud --project 'project' iam service-accounts create kube-cert-manager-sv-security --display-name "kube-cert-manager-sv-security"

  gcloud --project 'project' iam service-accounts keys create ~/.config/gcloud/kube-cert-manager-sv-security.json --iam-account kube-cert-manager-sv-security@'project'.iam.gserviceaccount.com

  gcloud --project 'project' projects add-iam-policy-binding  --member serviceAccount:kube-cert-manager-sv-security@'project'.iam.gserviceaccount.com --role roles/dns.admin

  kubectl create secret generic kube-cert-manager-sv-security-secret --from-file=/home/perre/.config/gcloud/kube-cert-manager-sv-security.json

and created the following resources:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: kube-cert-manager-sv-security-data
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi

apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: kube-cert-manager-sv-security
  namespace: default
---
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
    name: kube-cert-manager-sv-security
rules:
  - apiGroups: ["*"]
    resources: ["certificates", "ingresses"]
    verbs: ["get", "list", "watch"]
  - apiGroups: ["*"]
    resources: ["secrets"]
    verbs: ["get", "list", "create", "update", "delete"]
  - apiGroups: ["*"]
    resources: ["events"]
    verbs: ["create"]
---
kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1beta1
metadata:
  name: kube-cert-manager-sv-security-service-account
subjects:
  - kind: ServiceAccount
    namespace: default
    name: kube-cert-manager-sv-security
roleRef:
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: kube-cert-manager-sv-security
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
apiVersion: apiextensions.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: CustomResourceDefinition
metadata:
  name: certificates.stable.k8s.psg.io
spec:
  scope: Namespaced
  group: stable.k8s.psg.io
  version: v1
  names:
    kind: Certificate
    plural: certificates
    singular: certificate
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: kube-cert-manager-sv-security
  name: kube-cert-manager-sv-security
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kube-cert-manager-sv-security
      name: kube-cert-manager-sv-security
    spec:
      serviceAccount: kube-cert-manager-sv-security
      containers:
        - name: kube-cert-manager
          env:
          - name: GCE_PROJECT
            value: solidair-vlaanderen-207315
          - name: GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
            value: /opt/google/kube-cert-manager.json
          image: bcawthra/kube-cert-manager:2017-12-10
          args:
            - "-data-dir=/var/lib/cert-manager-sv-security"
            #- "-acme-url=https://acme-staging.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
            # NOTE: the URL above points to the staging server, where you won't get real certs.
            # Uncomment the line below to use the production LetsEncrypt server:
            - "-acme-url=https://acme-v01.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
            # You can run multiple instances of kube-cert-manager for the same namespace(s),
            # each watching for a different value for the 'class' label
            - "-class=kube-cert-manager"
            # You can choose to monitor only some namespaces, otherwise all namespaces will be monitored
            #- "-namespaces=default,test"
            # If you set a default email, you can omit the field/annotation from Certificates/Ingresses
            - "-default-email=viae.it@gmail.com"
            # If you set a default provider, you can omit the field/annotation from Certificates/Ingresses
            - "-default-provider=googlecloud"
          volumeMounts:
            - name: data-sv-security
              mountPath: /var/lib/cert-manager-sv-security
            - name: google-application-credentials
              mountPath: /opt/google
      volumes:
        - name: data-sv-security
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: kube-cert-manager-sv-security-data
        - name: google-application-credentials
          secret:
            secretName: kube-cert-manager-sv-security-secret
```

**anyone knows what I'm missing?**

Comment: This question should be migrated to Server Fault where it will be addressed better.

Answer (score 0):

Your secret resource `kube-cert-manager-sv-security-secret` may contains a JSON file named `kube-cert-manager-sv-security.json` and it is not matched with `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` value. You can confirm file name in the secret resource with `kubectl get secret -oyaml YOUR-SECRET-NAME`.

So you change the file path to the actual file name, cert-manager works fine.

```
- name: GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
#  value: /opt/google/kube-cert-manager.json
  value: /opt/google/kube-cert-manager-sv-security.json
```